# Ambiguites in AspNet Core 2.0 using Swagger in Web API

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use Swagger in an AspNet Core 2 Web API.  I have one sample that works based on:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?tabs=visual-studio

However, when I try to use the same approach in another service I get compile error:

2>Startup.cs(41,17,41,27): error CS0121:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder,
>   System.Action)'

and

> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder,
>   string, System.Action)'
>
> 2>Done building project "SocialNetwork.Api.csproj" -- FAILED.

The target call is in Startup.cs in the Configure method.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger(); // Ambiguous

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SocialNetwork API V1");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Does anyone have insight on this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Seems you are trapped in extension method ambigoius references problem. Try remove usings and calling them explicitly. For example you can use `MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(app);` instead of `app.UseMvc();`

Comment: I have this problem, trying to remove NSwag, but can't seem to get rid of NSwag. If I remove NSwag and installed swashbuckle I end up with: CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.NSwagApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder, System.Action<NSwag.AspNetCore.SwaggerDocumentMiddlewareSettings>)and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder, System.Action<Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerOptions>)

Answer (score 5):

I uninstalled Swagger and just installed the SwashBuckle.AspNetCore because it already implements the Swagger object inside. that is why it is calling ambigious.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you have references to multiple Swagger-libraries? In my case I had accidentally added a reference to other swagger-related Nuget packages, and that caused the same error as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the Swagger nugget package and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is

**app.UseSwagger((Action)null!);**